# Deal with Large Data in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report in our Membership Management System which we are developing on Asp.net, c# and SQL Server.

Currently the database has more than 100000 rows in the table and will keep on growing with time & organization.

The issue we are facing is regarding performance. The speed of the reports is too slow. On a local machine, it works great but when it's hosted on a server, it takes a long time  loading and navigating from one page to another. When user navigates to the next page, it will wait for up to 2-3 mins each time.

It is a single report, i.e. no sub reports.

I have already checked out with database indexes, but still no major improvements.

Kindly suggest me how should I deal with this issue. If any body know how to do pagination in Crystal as we perform on grid please let me know.

Comment: Are you displaying individual records or summarising the information?

Answer (score 0):

How often are you running the report? Is this information that is needed hourly or is this just a daily  update report?

If it is the latter then what I suggest is using a report server to generate the report once and export the data as a PDF. The report can be generated during off hours. It can then be stored on the server or sent by email to the neccessary parties. This way you don't have to keep hitting the DB each time someone needs the report.